# Syntax error with array passed to where in

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, typeorm

I'm using typeorm

Here's the code:

```
const validatorQb = await this.validatorRepository
  .createQueryBuilder('v')
  .distinctOn(['v_id'])
  .select('vb_createdAt', 'createdAt')
  .innerJoin(ValidatorBalance, 'vb', 'vb_validatorId = v.id')
  .where('v_clientId IN (:...ids)', { ids: clientIds })
  .orderBy('v_id, vb_createdAt', 'DESC');
```

And for whatever reason, I'm getting an error:

```
[Nest] 41   - 06/08/2021, 11:01:55 AM   [ExceptionsHandler] syntax error at or near ":" +5200ms
QueryFailedError: syntax error at or near ":"
```

I tried to use this comment as reference: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/1239#issuecomment-366955628

clientIds is a valid variable, and is an array of strings.

Comment: If you turn on logging for TypeORM, do you see the query written as expected?

Comment: @JayMcDoniel No. It's as it typeorm doesn't understand the :... syntax, since it translates it directly. Not as a variable

Comment: I tested both mysql and postgres using typorm 0.2.34, the `(:...ids)` syntax can do its job without problem. Is there any chance you can share your repo for us to debug?

Comment: My bad. I didn't realize adding using the .getSql() mattered, but that's what was causing issues.